# No opportunity to override name attribute for @Html.TextBoxFor in asp.net core 3.1

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, razor, html-helper

We are migrating our project from .net Framework 4.72 to .net core 3.1.

I have next html helper code:

`@Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.Property, "{0:0}", htmlAttributes: new { maxlength = 8, Name = "Model2.Property" })`

But when I inspect html code, name attribute is not overridden.
How can I override it?
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `TextBox`:

```
@Html.TextBox("Model2.Property",Model.Property,new { maxlength = 8})
```

or use `asp-for` and `name`:

```
<input asp-for="@Model.Property" name="Model2.Property" maxlength="8"/>
```

Pass data with prefix in form,and validate it in the action(ModelState.IsValid'),then return the error message to your view,but i think it's not a good idea,i think you don't need prefix in you controller action:

Here is a demo:

TestController:

```
  public IActionResult TestPrefix([Bind(Prefix = "Model2")]DataModel model) {
        if (ModelState.IsValid) {
            return Ok("success");
        }
        string message=string.Join("; ", ModelState.Values
                     .SelectMany(x => x.Errors)
                     .Select(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.ErrorMessage) ? x.ErrorMessage : x.Exception.Message.ToString()));

        return Ok(message);
    }
    public IActionResult TestDataModel() {
        return View();
    }
```

TestDataModel.cshtml:

```
 <form method="post">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.Property, "{0:0}", htmlAttributes: new { maxlength = 8 })
    <div style="color:red" id="errormessage">@TempData["Error"]</div>
    <button onclick="postModel()">post</button>
</form>
@section scripts{ 
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function postModel() {
            var formdata = new FormData();
            formdata.append("Model2.Property", $("#Property").val());
             $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                 url: '@Url.Action("TestPrefix", "Test")',
                 contentType: false,
                 processData: false,
                 data: formdata,
             }).done(function (data) {
                 //$("#errormessage").append(data);

    });
        }
    </script>
}
```

DataModel:

```
public class DataModel
    {
        [Required]
        [Range(0,5)]
        public int Property { get; set; }
    }
```

result:
[image]

Comment: Also tried, but my property has some validation attributes (e.g. required, range and so on) and when you use @Html.TextBox there are no attributes

Comment: Yes,it's because model binding is binded with the name,if you override the name,the model binding validation will disappear,and when you use form passed the model to action,you will find the property to be null.

Comment: like this: `<input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Property must be a number." data-val-required="Filed Property is required" id="Property" maxlength="8" name="Property" type="text" value="0">`

Comment: But when I use `@Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.Property)` - there are html attributes for validation and in .net framework it works (name was overridden and validation worked)

Comment: Yes,when you don't override the name,use like `@Html.TextBox("Property",Model.Property,new { maxlength = 8})`,it  also have validation

Comment: Ok, and how can I save client side validation and change Name attribute value?

Comment: No,if you change the name,it will not be binded.So in .net core,you'd better not change the name,you can change id.

Comment: I need to change name because it's form element and in controller I have next signature of method: `public ActionResult SaveModel([Bind(Prefix = "Model2")]DataModel model`

Comment: I think you can use ajax with formdata to pass data when form post.I have updated my answer about it.